# PHP trim value xxxx.xxxx to xxxx,xx

Tags: php, magento, trim

We have been working on some configurations on our Magento supported website, but we have a problem with our price.

What we want to have is that when the PHP gets a value, it needs to trim it in just the right way to get a proper display.

Example:

Input: 107.9400 
Output: 107,94

```
<?php echo nl2br ($_product->getmsrp())?><br><?php endif; ?>
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/eis1R4v.png]

to:

[image]

The second picture is edited in HTML in the browser, so it's not fixed yet!
We've been looking for trims but we couldn't find anything unfortunately. We also are very new to this programming language...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Very simple google search *format number php* - first result

Comment: @Novocaine and how would he have know to search for that? i would have searched for something like variable trim.

Comment: @djeroen common sense really. Changing the format of a number is the end goal and php is the coding language referenced. Hence the 3 keywords - seems pretty obvious to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$number = number_format ($number , 2 , ',' , '.')
```

Using:

> string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string
>   $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Though knowing Magento, I would not be surprised that there are Magento specific solutions to these kinds of problems, seeing its one of the most complete e-commerce packages

Comment: Could you please show how my code should look like, using my example code I supplied

Comment: <?php echo nl2br (number_format ($_product->getmsrp() , 2 , ',' , '.'))?><br><?php endif; ?>
Though this seems very ugly to me.

Comment: Thank you very much! Have nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for get any price with currency and two decimal format :-

```
  `Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getmsrp(),true,false);`
```